# Perl get value of a key

Tags: perl

I have been stuck in trying to create an array of keys (example_com,example_ca ..etc) if they are set to 1, I have tried using for loop and foreach loop, but keep getting ARRAY# error.

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'example_com' => '1',
        'example_ca' => '1'
      }
    ];
```

Thanks

Comment: `if ($VAR1->[0]{example_com} == 1)` since $VAR1 is an array that only contains one element which is a hash.

Comment: I'm actually trying to loop thorugh it, there could be more than one key

Comment: Then show a bit more of the context. _There could be more than one key_  => What do you mean with that? More than one element in the array? You already have more than one key, but you want to check a specific and already known one (example_com) according to your question.

Comment: I have modified my question as per your comment and added more context.

Comment: The square brackets indicate an array. This array currently only has one element, and it is a hash (indicated by the curly brackets). This hash contains 2 keys, `example_com` and `example_ca`, the value of which is 1 for both. Do you want: more elements in the array, or more keys inside the hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An expanded example of how to get an array of keys if you have multiple hashes in your container array:

```
my $VAR1 = [
        {
          'example_com' => '1',
          'example_ca'  => '1',
          'not_set'      => '0'
        },
        {
          'EXAMPLE_com' => '1',
          'EXAMPLE_ca'  => '1',
          'NOT_SET'      => '0',
        }
];

my @arrayOfHashes = @{$VAR1};

foreach my $array (@arrayOfHashes)
{
    my @onlyOnes; 
    my @arrayOfKeys = sort keys %{$array};
    foreach my $key (@arrayOfKeys)
    {
        next if ($array->{$key} ne 1); 
        push @onlyOnes, $key;
    }

    print "\nKey names:\n";
    foreach my $key (@onlyOnes)
    {
        print "$key\n";
    }
}
```

output:

```
Key names:
example_ca
example_com

Key names:
EXAMPLE_ca
EXAMPLE_com
```

Answer (score 4):

This will be because you have an array containing a hash. The array is one element long.

So you 'get' to the hash, by dereferencing element zero.

Thus:

```
my $hash_ref = $VAR1->[0]; 
print join "\n", keys %{$hash_ref},"\n"; 

foreach my $key ( keys %{$VAR1->[0]} ) {
   print "$key => $VAR1->[0]{$key}\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the $VAR1 "array containing a hash" is just the output of Data::Dumper and not his real variable.

Comment: It is, but without a more specific example, I cannot give a more specific answer. The input to `Dumper` would have to be an array ref (either a scalar, or `\@array`) to produce that output.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly for you source data:

```
my @array_of_keys =  ();

for( keys %{ $VAR1->[0] } ) {
    push @array_of_keys, $_   if $VAR1->[0]{ $_ } eq '1';
}

print "Keys with 1: @array_of_keys";
```